# AJAX Autocomplete performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

How to improve AJAX autocomplete performance?

Answer (score 3):

Caching, both clientside and serverside.

Answer (score 1):

This recent [link](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/) from flickr developers may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

See here on .NET server side implementation:
http://metalthought.blogspot.com/2009/05/enhanced-performance-for-aspnet-ajax.html